# In Vim is there a corresponding change (c) command for paste (p)?

Tags: vim, copy-paste, paste, yank

With insertions, it is very easy to both wipe out a word/section and insert over it, like so

- `cw` delete until end of word (with space) then go to insert mode
- `ce` delete until end of word (without space) then go to insert mode
- `c3w` delete until end of the next 3 words (with space) then go to insert mode
- `ct.` delete until before period then go to insert mode
- `c$` delete until end of line then go to insert mode

How do I do this with paste operations? Often times I have a line like so

```
var name = "John Smith"
var name = "Jane Smith"
```

And I change it to

```
var name = "John Lee"
var name = "Jane Smith"
```

And yank (`yw`) "Lee", but now if I delete (`dw`) "Smith" from "Jane Smith", I no longer have "Lee" in the register to paste back. I know I can use the named registers. Also, I am sure I can use visual mode. However, I figured since this is a pretty common task, there would be a way to use the movement operators (`e`, `w`, `t`/`T`, `f`/`F`,`$`,`0`) with the paste command to specify what to paste over.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think visual mode is the way to go. You just enable visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> (if you want to overwrite whole lines at the time), use the movement operators in the usual way to select the area to be replaced and then paste. You take advantage of what you already know.

<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> overwrites the current line. <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> overwrites the current word.

You can find an overview of the alternatives at the [Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text#How_to_copy.2Fpaste).

Answer (score 10):

Oh yes, what you want is the ultra convenient (sarcasm) blackhole register: select in visual mode the part you want to replace, using the movement you want (like `vw`), then <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

The black hole register `_` is a special register akin to `/dev/null`. The operation `"` sets the destination register for the text you are about to replace, and thus `"_` ensures that the unwanted "Smith" hits the blackhole register. Thus, "Lee" is preserved in the `"` register. I'd recommend using macros to help if you're doing this many times in a row.

Comment: I realize this answer is complicated and mixes several concepts - hope it's helpful though, and would love to see if there are better ways to accomplish this. This is merely the best way I can think of (and that I use fairly often).

Comment: It really is just a different way of approaching the paste to registers. +1 for referencing `/dev/null` though

Answer (score 4):

```
I no longer have "Lee" in the register to paste back.
```

Actually, `Lee` is in `reg:0`, there are at least two ways to paste back.

#### Method 1

- move cursor to `Lee`, <kbd>yw</kbd>
- move cursor to `Smith`, <kbd>dw</kbd>
- <kbd>"0P</kbd>

#### Method 2

- move cursor to `Lee`, <kbd>yw</kbd>
- move cursor to `Smith`, <kbd>cw</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a custom mapping, I have the following:

`nnoremap ,pw viw"0p`

Which pastes over the `inner word (iw)` the last yanked text. Note that I'm using the 0 register, so I can paste as many times as I want, without loosing the yanked text. Unfortunately you need to write some other mappings. I like to have a mapping to paste `inside quote`, `inside brackets` and `inside parentheses`:

```
nnoremap ,pi" vi""0p
nnoremap ,pi] vi]"0p
nnoremap ,pi) vi)"0p
```

Comment: I wonder if it is practical to right a mapping which accepts arguments then always uses register 0